# Flutter Row widget solve RenderFlex overflow by cutting off remaining area

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are a lot of questions here already about `Renderflex` overflow, but I believe my use case might be a bit different.

Just the usual problem - having a `Widget` that is too big in a `Row` widget, and I get the `A RenderFlex overflowed by X pixels ...` error.

I want to create a Row that cuts off it's overflowing child `Widget` if they would be rendered outside it's area without getting an error.

First off, **wrapping the last element in the `Row` widget with `Expanded` or `Flexible` does not work** in my case, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088925/4420543) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650374/4420543) and many other places. Please see code and image:

```dart
class PlayArea extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dummyChild = Container(
      color: Colors.black12,
      width: 100,
      child: Text('important text'),
    );

    final fadeContainer = Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          colors: [
            Colors.black26,
            Colors.black87,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      width: 600,
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                dummyChild,
                fadeContainer,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                dummyChild,
                Expanded(
                  child: fadeContainer,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  width: 1100,
                  child: Text('important text'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: fadeContainer,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Overflow cases]

Key points:

- Using `Expanded` changes the width of `Container`, which changes the gradient's slope. I want to keep the gradient as it is
- Even with `Expanded` widget, the `Row` is not prepared for the case when `important text`'s area is too wide and does not fit the screen horizontally - it will get an overflow error for that Widget
- it is technically working in the first case, because no red color is drawn on the right side on the green field, it 'just' has an error

---

How do I cut off the remaining space dynamically without any error - regardless of any screen size and content?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found is that

```dart
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        dummyChild,
        fadeContainer,
    ],
)
```

can be converted to

```dart
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
        dummyChild,
        fadeContainer,
    ],
)
```

Creating a horizontal list and preventing scroll on that.

---

edit.: just found out it that [you'll get unbounded vertical height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50155738/4420543), so it's not the same.